# How would you write a For Loop that advances the currentFrame by 1 if it is below a certain Frame

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I just need the correct syntax ... I keep getting errors.

Current code looks like this:

```
for (var i = movieClip.currentFrame; i<15; i++){

   movieClip.currentFrame+1

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? If you want to play from a specified frame to another frame, this is not the way to go. That said, I don't undstand the current answers that are given. `MovieClip.currentFrame` is a **read-only** property. So none of the answers would actually work, none tested their code. I downvoted the answers for that. This is why you get errors too.

```
myMc.currentFrame = 5; 
// gives an error, since this property is read-only, you cannot set it.
```

To jump to a certain frame, use `gotoAndStop()` or `gotoAndPlay()`, with the framenumber or framelabel as the parameter.

If you want to play a clip called `myMc` from the current frame to (lets say) frame *15*, try this

```
myMc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
 if (myMc.currentFrame < 15)
 {
   myMc.gotoAndStop(myMc.currentFrame + 1);
 }
}
```

As you can see we've created an enterframe listener. If you dont understand what it does; this makes the `onEnterFrame` function (defined below) execute every frame. Its needed because every frame it have to decide where to go, its not possible with a loop. It should be altered over time. This example works, but only if when you should play forward, or to be more specific; when `currentFrame` is under `15`. If your at fram 20, your stuck. Lets fix that by make it play backwards too, if needed.

```
myMc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
 if (myMc.currentFrame < 15)
 {
   myMc.gotoAndStop(myMc.currentFrame + 1);
 }
 else if (myMc.currentFrame > 15)
 {
   myMc.gotoAndStop(myMc.currentFrame - 1);
 }
}
```

ok, now it should also play backwards. Now, it would be betterr to stop checking when we've arrived at the target frame. Therefor we should remove the eventlistener.

```
myMc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
 if (myMc.currentFrame < 15)
 {
   myMc.gotoAndStop(myMc.currentFrame + 1);
 }
 else if (myMc.currentFrame > 15)
 {
   myMc.gotoAndStop(myMc.currentFrame - 1);
 }
 if (myMc.currentFrame == 15)
 {
   myMc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
 }
}
```

Now this should be the answer of your question. However it would be nice to make a function where you can give a target movieclip and endFrame.

```
function playClipTo(clip:MovieClip, targetFrame:int):void
{
  clip.targetFrame = targetFrame;
  // since MovieClip is dynamic, you can add non-excisting properties. 
  // If your using classes, you would extend MovieClip and create a public variable for this. But for now its fine.
  clip.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onClipEnterFrame);
}

function onClipEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
 var clip:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target); // this referres to any clip with a listener
 if (clip.targetFrame)
 {
  if (clip.currentFrame < clip.targetFrame)
  {
   clip.gotoAndStop(clip.currentFrame + 1);
  }
  else if (clip.currentFrame > clip.targetFrame)
  {
   clip.gotoAndStop(clip.currentFrame - 1);
  }
  if (clip.currentFrame == clip.targetFrame)
  {
   clip.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onClipEnterFrame);
   delete clip.targetFrame;
  }
 }
 else
 {
   clip.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onClipEnterFrame);
 }
}
```

With this function you could do this

```
playClipTo(myMc, 15); // ha, familiar example!
playClipTo(myMc2, 5); // another clip, play to frame 5
```

I hope this helps. By the way, if you need to jump from framelabel to framelabel, or need more control on speed, easing, delays, you could take a look at a tween engine, like [TweenLite](http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/), this has very advanced but easy to understand way of animating with code. Its very common in the flash world, plus it saves development time for relative simple tasks like this.

Comment: I am using the keyboardEvent. and what happens is that instead of flowing through my movie clip it continuously restarts it at frame one. if I had created a button for the movie clip to play in as3 it plays it all the way through. So I need a function that detects if it is recycling the keyboard event and to continue through the frames on the timeline instead of restarting.

Comment: I've made a small mistake on the delete function, it should be "delete clip.targetFrame;" instead of currentFrame. I've updated the post. Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

inside the loop put

```
if (movieClip.currentFrame < theNumberToIncreaseTo) {
     movieClip.currentFrame = movieClip.currentFrame + 1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tested the code? MovieClip.currentFrame is a read-only property. This code gives a compile error..

Answer (score -2):

Maybe

```
movieClip.currentFrame = movieClip.currentFrame + 1
```

Instead of

```
movieClip.currentFrame+1
```

Comment: Have you tested the code? MovieClip.currentFrame is a read-only property. This code gives a compile error..